# Why spark blas use f2jBLAS instead of native BLAS for level 1 routines?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, blas

I found the following code in BLAS.scala:

```
// For level-1 routines, we use Java implementation.
private def f2jBLAS: NetlibBLAS = {
  if (_f2jBLAS == null) {
    _f2jBLAS = new F2jBLAS
  }
  _f2jBLAS
}
```

I think the native blas is faster than a pure Java implementation.

So why spark choose the f2jblas for level 1 routines, Is there any reason I do not know?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most likely to be found in the *Performance* section of the readme file of the [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-Java) repository.

> Java has a reputation with older generation developers because Java applications were slow in the 1990s. Nowadays, the JIT ensures that Java applications keep pace with – or exceed the performance of – C / C++ / Fortran applications.

This is followed by charts showing detailed benchmark results for various BLAS routines in both pure Java (translated from Fortran with f2j) and from native BLAS on both Linux on ARM and macOS on x86_64. The `ddot` benchmark shows that on x86 (JRE for ARM doesn't seem to have JIT capabilities) F2J performs on par with the reference native BLAS implementation for longer vector sizes and even outperforms it for shorter vector sizes. The caveat here is that the JIT kicks in after a couple of invocations, which is not a problem as most ML algorithms are iterative in nature. Most of the level 1 routines are fairly simple and the JIT compiler is able to generate well optimised code. This is also why the tuning efforts in highly optimised BLAS implementations go into the level 2 and 3 routines.